# iOS 6 how to post a picture in facebook fan page

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, ipad

Any of you knows if on iOS 6 facebook integreation you can post a picture on facebook fan page and how can be implemented?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: use http://www.mobile.safilsunny.com/integrating-facebook-ios-6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope, the GitHub project will easily solve your problem.** [Click here.](https://github.com/yashesh87/Social-Framework-iOS6)